# Mismatch in OSversion and other properties for Aspnet image on AppVeyor

Tags: docker, docker-image, appveyor, .net-4.8

I am facing a very peculiar issue. I am using AppVeyor for my CI/CD and apparently the OS version of  `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8` image is different on AppVeyor server and on my system.
This is what I get when I inspect the image on AppVeyor

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "windows",
        "OsVersion": "10.0.17763.1637",
        "Size": 8424507509,
        "VirtualSize": 8424507509,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\299141c3a9068896ce9f5928d7b9174570a2ef0b5f59a9b45ca0d768c3a09206"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
```

as compared to this, which is what I have on my system

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "windows",
        "OsVersion": "10.0.19041.685",
        "Size": 5541468778,
        "VirtualSize": 5541468778,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\c9c52e1316159499618a9c15b326fdc7457db4f4de07af590039086de5bc82e0"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
```

There is a difference between OS  version and other properties. So I tried pulling the images again on the basis of digest

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet@sha256:d7adec80a9a43d801891458040018972ac006aeca2903cdc6369f69f54951b22
```

but nothing gets updated.
The problem this is causing is that I have custom image that gets build on my system that has an OSversion `"OsVersion": "10.0.19041.685"`. This image is used by Appveyor to build my final image, and as expected this throws an error as explained in [Microsoft Container Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-20H2%2Cwindows-10-20H2).

Can anyone help me understand why that's happening.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppVeyor image is based on Windows Server 2019, so 10.0.17763 is the latest version of base image that can be run on AppVeyor. You are on Windows 10 version 2004 which is build 10.0.19041.

Comment: Yes, I figured that after looking at the official documentation for both Appveyor and Aspnet images. So just for my info Appveyor only support Windows server images ?

Comment: We can provide "Windows Server 2004"-based image as a paid option.

Comment: Although I think we have paid membership, but we are good for now.Thanks !